# Can I conditionally adjust list item height in React Native based on a user's accessibility setting?

Tags: javascript, css, layout, react-native, accessibility

I'm working on a React Native app that uses FlatList to render rows of data.  Each row contains an icon on the left and an item title and description on the right.  We expect the user age range of this app to be pretty large, and therefore one of our device tests involves launching the app with the phone's vision settings set to full zoom with font size large.  Currently the row heights are set firm at 100px.

The problem this is presenting is certain rows with longer text data are having the text cut off on the top and bottom.  I'm looking for a way to conditionally change the height of the rows based on the device's accessibility settings.

I would like to render all rows with the same height with the ability to accommodate any vision setting.  The rows need to all be the same height, so I can't leave the height blank to accommodate any amount of data since this will render short rows for less text and tall rows for more text.

Also, I haven't seen a way to read a device's vision settings from React Native.  Is there a way?

Thank you and sorry if this is an easy or obvious fix!

Comment: have you got any solution for conditionally height base on index number....

Comment: @RamS you can get the index of the item being sent to your renderItem function.  Instead of just deconstructing the item with ({ item }) you would use ({ item, index }).  The you can apply a height based off of that.  Does that help?